# An Eigenvalue of $A^3$ is an Eigenvalue of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A^3$ be a matrix who has a Jordan Normal Form of the following:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}8 & 1 & 0\\0 & 8 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$$

Calculating the characteristic polynomial of this matrix:

$P_x=(\lambda-1)(\lambda-8)^2$

From above I can conclude that $\lambda=1,\lambda=8$ are the only eigenvalues of $A^3$.

Are these eigenvalues, are the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$? How can I know/verify it? Maybe $\sqrt[3]{\lambda}$ is the eigenvalues?

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: What do you mean by similar?

Comment: @anubhav https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity

Comment: @anubhav sorry I have edited my post. $A^3$ now has a Jordan Normal Form.

Comment: If $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A$, $\lambda^{3}$ is eigenvalue of $A^{3}$ so i guess not.

Comment: @Stravog thank you. How do I prove your comment? I thought so.

Comment: @Stravog $Av=\lambda v$ $\rightarrow$ $A^3v=\lambda^3v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$8$ will not be an eigenvalue of $A$ and $1$ may or may not be (depending upon whether $A$ has complex-valued entries or not). This is because:

Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenvector $\vec{x}$. Then we have: $A^n\vec{x}=A^{n-1}A\vec{x}=\lambda A^{n-1}\vec{x}=\lambda A^{n-2}A\vec{x}=\lambda^2 A^{n-2}\vec{x}=...=\lambda^n\vec{x}$.

So, $2=8^{1/3}$ will be an eigenvalue for sure. But depending upon the form for $A$, then $1$ or a cube root of unity may be the third eigenvalue.

Comment: Thank you. Why does it matter that the entries will be in $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @Alan If one of the eigenvalues of $A$ is a complex cube root of unity, then the corresponding eigenvalue of $A^3$ will be $1$. If $A$ has real entries, then this complex eigenvalue would have to come with its conjugate, but it can't, because the other two eigenvalues are already "taken". But it could if $A$ had complex entries. One mistake in the above is that I think even if $A$ has real entries, $2$ times a complex cube root of unity could be an eigenvalue of $A$.